# Search Bar in Native Meassage App in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiview, uitextview

I need to know that what type of VIEW is used in the search bar of Create Message Screen. The bar searches , adds tabs as per the contacts selected and and also gives the option of selecting contacts form contact list througha button.

I am not able to understand whether it is a UITextView ot a UIView with variable size of UITextView.

Can Anyone please help me out in this regard.

Thsnks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has yet answered my problem, and I have found the solution so will answer my own problem.

Yes, the search bar used in the native application is a UIScrollview with variable sized UITextView that converts the selected name into Number.

Thanks